# Google script doPost to Twilio

Tags: google-apps-script, twilio

I trying to use doPost in google script to get parameter from source A and get twilio to send sms.
Currently, by using the code given by twilio, I can send whatever detail in google script.
I have created the webapp exec url to put in source A so now source A and google script can communicating.

I just do not know how to do a proper script in google script to get the parameters from source A.
Can anyone help me.. thank you in advance !
I am new to coding, not sure even source A code/format is correct -_-"

**Source A:(json)**
[data input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdZww.png)

output result

```
{
  "$type": "Nirvana.Data.TaskResultWebhook, V2API",
  "Headers": {
    "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]], mscorlib",
    "Authorization": "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=="
  },
  "Payload": "{\"To\": \"+8888888888\",\"Body\": \"testing\",\"From\" : \"business\"}",
  "Url": "https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxxxxxxxxx/exec",
  "Verb": "Post",
  "ContentType": "JSON",
  "MimeType": "application/json",
  "TimeoutSeconds": 180,
  "MaxRetryCount": 3,
  "AsyncExec": false,
  "AppErrors": {
    "$type": "Jeenee.DataTypes.AppErrors, Jeenee.DataTypes",
    "RecordInfo": false,
    "RecordWarning": true,
    "AnnotateErrors": false,
    "Errors": []
  },
  "TaskType": "Webhook",
  "TaskName": "New Task"
}
```

**Google script (code from twilio)**

```
function doPost(e) {
  var messages_url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxxx/Messages.json";

  var payload = {
    "To": "+1111111111",
    "Body" : "AAAAAAAAAA",
    "From" : "BBBBBBBBBB"
  };

  var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : payload
  };

  options.headers = { 
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("ACxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxx")
  };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(messages_url, options);
}
```

**Step 3 (twilio)**
send sms

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure who's calling your script. If you're using it as a webhook you can get the parameters in the object passed into your `doPost` function when it is called.

```
    function doPost(e) {

var params = e.parameter;
var from = params.From;
var to = params.To;
var body = params.Body;

      var messages_url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxxx/Messages.json";
    
      var payload = {
        "To": to,
        "Body" : body,
        "From" : from
      };
    
      var options = {
        "method" : "post",
        "payload" : payload
      };
    
      options.headers = { 
        "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("ACxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxx")
      };
    
      UrlFetchApp.fetch(messages_url, options);
    }
```

Comment: Hi jack thanks for assisting.
I am using as webhook
Execute as : ME
who has access: Anyone

Not sure why the status failed again

Comment: I am new to script, is there anymore info that I can provide u for easy assist

Comment: I see from some post got this part, not sure how to construct and whether it help or not, 'payload' : JSON.stringify(e['parameters'][0])

Comment: You must allow Anyone even anonymous in order for Twilio to send something to your webhook. Twilio won't post to a private URL

Comment: If it works please accept answer

Comment: Hi Jack, I already set the "who has access to (Anyone)". There are only 3 option under the new App-script editor, who have access: Only me, Anyone with Google account, Anyone.

Comment: Do you need access to take a look, you can email me your Gmail address to my test account: testingdownloadimage@gmail.com , I will share access with you.

Comment: @167 you would have to see if the parameters are coming in. the way to check would be to log them out or `appendRow()` to see the results

Comment: Hi Jack, can u email me your Gmail address, I will share with you my access for Source A and google script, your code seem right to me but not sure where have I done wrong, the status just show failed

Comment: @167 I don't think I will be able to help you by sharing my email address, besides I rather not. I'm not sure if the parameters you posted are the real ones you're sending to the Google script. If yes the `To` and `From` parameters are not valid. they shoud be both valid E164 format for example `To=+18884445555` and `From=+16668889999`

Comment: the parameters I post in Source A are only example. What I trying to explain is to get data from Source A as parameter. of course, I will be using a real number to test.
Because Source A do not have the alphanumeric sender SMS function, so I need webhook to Google script then to twilio

Comment: To go through GAS is to get data from the Source A and also to replace the From="alpha sender" to send twilio

Comment: Why don't you `console.log(to,from,body)` to see if the parameters are coming through. I can't really help you with your source A since I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Thank you for being patient with me, i am very new to script. I take some screenshot but not sure how to put in comment to show u of the error. Anyway, I put in the code "console.log(to,from,body)" after var body = params.Body; where and how to see the log, dopost cannot just run on the script right? it show cannot read property 'parameter'. When i trigger with Source A, the execution only show status failed, no option for me to check to view log. I see post saying need to use old editor run, view stackdriver logging but it ask view in google cloud platform which i not sure how